# Writing wide string to a file in byte mode stopped

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring

I am writing out unicode text (stored as `wstring`) into a file and I'm doing it in byte mode, but the string in the file ends prior to "™" character being printed. Is "™" not unicode or am I doing something wrong?

```
wofstream output;
outp.open("output.txt", ofstream::binary);
wstring a =L"ABC™";
output << a;
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file with `ofstream::binary` when you want to write to it using formatted output (i.e., with `<<`)?

Answer (score 0):

TM is definitely unicode. ofstream and wofstream do not write the text in UTF-8 format. You've to encode the output buffer in UTF-8 in order to see the results you're expecting. So, try using "WideCharToMultiByte".

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception about the iostream binary mode: that it is to read/write binary files. The iostream library works only with text files and only read and write text files. The only thing the the "binary" mode changes is how NL (new line) characters are handled. In binary more, no transformation occurs. In non-binary mode, writing LF characters ('\n') to a stream will convert it to the platform specific new line sequence (Unix -> LF, Windows -> CR LF ("\r\n"), Mac -> CR) while when reading, the platform specific new line sequence will be converted to a single LF ('\n') character.

For everything else, nothing changes, meaning an wofstream will always convert the Unicode wide character string to single byte or multi byte character stream depending on the locale used by your process. If you have a locale of "en_US.utf8" on Linux for example, it will be converted to UTF8. Now, if the current locale does not have a representation for the TM Unicode symbol, then either nothing or a '?' will be written to the file.

Comment: Could you please provide a way to fix the problem. I would be fine with it writing ? or nothing, but the printing process just ends after TM sign. If i have a string "ABC™ QWERTY" all there will be in the file "ABC".

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you on that, mainly because it is not clear exactly what you need (note that I said "need", not "want". One of the question is "why are you doing that?"). There is multiple ways to encode unicode characters into a file: UTF8, UTF16, UTF16LE and UTF16BE are the most common, but not the only ones methods available. Or may be you need the same encoding as used by your system, so that you can display them correctly.

Comment: The iostream library is relatively limited and only support a default translation scheme from Unicode to the current locale. So using iostream, your only option is to correctly set the locale of your process before writing to your files. For more control, you will need to use platform/OS specific APIs, or use external libraries (like ICU) for that.